# Autowired error spring

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-data-mongodb

I am new to spring. Previous I have used to configure the auto wiring using spring- context xml.
Now my project we are using annotation directly to inject the bean.

I am getting following exception when I try to auto wire Mongo repository.

Below is the sample code.

**StagingDocumentServiceImpl:**

```
@Service
public class StagingDocumentServiceImpl implements StagingDocumentService {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StagingDocumentServiceImpl.class);
@Autowired
private StagingDocumentRepository stagingDocumentRepository;

/**
 * 
 */
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public List<String> saveRawData(Tuple twitter) {

    List<String> tweetIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("Twitter information get passed.." + twitter);
    Status tweets = (Status) twitter
            .getValueByField(TopologyConstants.TWEETSPOUT_OUT_FIELD);
    //try{
    CIPPayload twitterPayload = DataCaptureTwitterUtil
            .getrawJSONPayloadFromTwitterResponse(tweets);
    String parentID = null;
    System.out.println("twitterPayload"+twitterPayload);
    String tweetParentId = twitterPayload.getContent().getParentContentId();
    /*if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(tweetParentId)) {
        DBObject queryObject = new BasicDBObject();
        queryObject.put("content.id", tweetParentId);
        DBObject resultedData = stagingDocumentRepository.fi
        if (resultedData == null) {
            parentID = getOriginalTweet(tweetParentId);
            tweetIDs.add(parentID);
        }

    }*/

    Test test = stagingDocumentRepository.save(twitterPayload);

    System.out.println("test-->"+test);


    return tweetIDs;
}
```

**StagingDocumentRepository:**

```
 public interface StagingDocumentRepository extends
  MongoRepository<CIPPayload, Serializable> {

 }
```

The problem is  I do know how to configure using **@bean** annotation.

I have tried to configure like below.

After all below answer I have changed the configuartion as below.

But changing this also does not work.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    @Bean
    public StagingDocumentRepository stagingDocumentRepository(){
        return new StagingDocumentRepository() {

            @Override
            public <S extends CIPPayload> S save(S entity) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public CIPPayload findOne(Serializable id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Iterable<CIPPayload> findAll(Iterable<Serializable> ids) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean exists(Serializable id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void deleteAll() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void delete(Iterable<? extends CIPPayload> entities) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void delete(CIPPayload entity) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void delete(Serializable id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public long count() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Page<CIPPayload> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public <S extends CIPPayload> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entites) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public List<CIPPayload> findAll(Sort sort) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public List<CIPPayload> findAll() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        };
}
```

**Output:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stagingDocumentServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.repository.payload.StagingDocumentRepository com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.processing.serviceImpl.StagingDocumentServiceImpl.stagingDocumentRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.repository.payload.StagingDocumentRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482) ~[spring-context-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952) [spring-boot-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941) [spring-boot-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.Application.main(Application.java:32) [classes/:na]
       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.repository.payload.StagingDocumentRepository com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.processing.serviceImpl.StagingDocumentServiceImpl.stagingDocumentRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.repository.payload.StagingDocumentRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.repository.payload.StagingDocumentRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
```

Comment: have you declared `StagingDocumentRepository` in your bean configuration file?

Comment: No. I do know how to do this. I used to do in spring-context file. I do know how to inject using @Bean annotation.

Comment: Try to put this on your @Bean, @Qualifier("stagingDocumentRepository")

Comment: This is what I configured                                                                                                                       @Bean
  @Qualifier("stagingDocumentRepository")
  public StagingDocumentRepository stagingDocumentRepository(){
   
   
  }

Comment: [Solution to the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220058/unable-to-create-junit-test-for-spring-boot-controller/65456509#65456509)
This error results mainly due to folder structuring

Answer (score 2):

should be like this:

```
@Respository
public interface StagingDocumentRepository extends
MongoRepository<CIPPayload, Serializable> {

}
```

and then :

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class ThisIsAnAppConfigClass{

   @Bean 
   public StagingDocumentRepository stagingDocumentRepository(){
      return new StagingDocumentRepository();
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try defining this in your spring config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">

<bean class="path.to.your.stagingdocumentrepository" id="StagingDocumentRepository" />

</beans>
```

equivalent without xml is like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ThisIsAnAppConfigClass{

   @Bean 
   public StagingDocumentRepository stagingDocumentRepository(){
      return new StagingDocumentRepository();
   }
}
```

Comment: @Arno_Gesmar I have edited my configuration as per your suggestion. but still am getting the same exception.

Comment: Annotate your StagingDocumentRepository with @Repository

Comment: @Arno_Gesmar Sorry for troubling you every time. I have added Repository also but still the result is same

Comment: @Arno_Gesmar after the changes I am getting Cannot instantiate the type StagingDocumentRepository in ThisIsAnAppConfigClass class. I think I have to override the mongo repository methods

Comment: You should have a concrete class that implements the interface. Then your method : public StagingDocumentRepository stagingDocumentRepository(){
      return new StagingDocumentRepositoryImpl();
   } should return the implementation

Comment: did my last comment solve your problem ? Regards, Arno

Comment: @Arno_Gesmar sorry for late reply. give me some time. I will come back to you. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The error message

```
No qualifying bean of type [com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.repository.payload.StagingDocumentRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

tells you that spring found no `StagingDocumentRepository` bean that can be injected in your `StagingDocumentServiceImpl`.

You should make sure you define a `StagingDocumentRepository` bean. To do so you can use various ways.

- use xml configuration like Arno_Geismar showed in his answer
- use component scan feature and annotate `StagingDocumentRepository` with a scanned annotation (e.g. `@Repository`).
- use Java config to define the bean (like shown below)

Java config:

```
@Bean
public StagingDocumentRepository stagingDocumentRepository() {
  return new StagingDocumentRepository(..);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that it returns a null value.

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("stagingDocumentRepository")
public StagingDocumentRepository stagingDocumentRepository() {
  return new StagingDocumentRepository(..);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using @repository or @EnableMongoRepositories

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that when using Spring Data, the implementation of the repository specified is provided by Spring Data. You should **not** provide any such implementation.

In your case the implementation of `StagingDocumentRepository` would be provided by Spring Data if you have configured Spring Data correctly.

The fact that Spring reports that no bean of type `StagingDocumentRepository` exists, means that you have not setup Spring Data Mongo correctly.

Your Java config would look like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories("package.under.which.repositories.reside")
public class YourConfig {

    //whatever beans you need
}
```

Your repository does **not** need to contain any extra annotation to be picked up by Spring Data. It would just be:

```
public interface StagingDocumentRepository extends
  MongoRepository<CIPPayload, Serializable> {

}
```