# Spring autowired fails

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-data-mongodb

This question is related to which I asked morning.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238573/autowired-error-spring)

I am not able to solve after the answers posted for the above one.

So I tried the same with a test case to understand better and make it simple

I simplified the above question as below with a test case.

here I am trying to put the document into the mongo db.

This is what I test.

```
 @Document(collection = "test")
 public class Test implements Serializable {

 private String source = null;
 private long systemTime;
 }
```

**Test case:**

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = { MongoConfiguration.class})
   public class ApplicationTests {

  @Test
   public void thatDocumentRepositoryWorks() {

     Test tt= new Test();
    tt.setSystemTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
    tt.setSource("twitter");
    stagingDocumentRepository.save(payLoad);
 }
}
```

StagingDocumentRepository

```
 @Repository
 public interface StagingDocumentRepository extends
  MongoRepository<CIPPayload, Serializable> {

  }
```

**Output:**

```
       Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener    [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@46af28] to prepare test instance [com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.ApplicationTests@20956b3c]
   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.ApplicationTests': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.repository.payload.StagingDocumentRepository com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.ApplicationTests.stagingDocumentRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.repository.payload.StagingDocumentRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:384) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331) ~[spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309) [junit-4.11.jar:na]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176) [spring-test-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197) [.cp/:na]
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.repository.payload.StagingDocumentRepository com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.ApplicationTests.stagingDocumentRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.repository.payload.StagingDocumentRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
... 26 common frames omitted
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.biomorf.cip.datacapture.repository.payload.StagingDocumentRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) ~[spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
... 28 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I can't understand..was [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25239584/3548826) answer of any use?

Comment: @AlexGreg No it does not help me to solve the issue. I have edited my question.

Comment: Are there on your class ApplicationTests these annotations? (@ContextConfiguration, @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class), @TransactionConfiguration) .. can you add how to inject stagingDocumentRepository?

Comment: It would be best if you post the code for `StagingDocumentRepository` and the Spring configuration you are using

Comment: @bharathi Check out my answer to your original question

Answer (score 0):

Spring repositories should be auto-discovered (for Java config) using the `@Enable{type}Repositories` annotations (in this case [`@EnableMongoRepositories`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/config/EnableMongoRepositories.java)) on the configuration class file, which auto creates proxy instances for those interfaces. You don't nee the `@Repository` annotation. That doesn't do what you think it does.

Just annotate `MongoConfiguration` with it. From [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.6.0.M1/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html)

> If you'd rather like to go with JavaConfig use the @EnableMongoRepositories annotation. The annotation carries the very same attributes like the namespace element. If no base package is configured the infrastructure will scan the package of the annotated configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
class ApplicationConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

  @Override
  protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return "e-store";
  }

  @Override
  public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
    return new MongoClient();
  }

  @Override
  protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
    return "com.oreilly.springdata.mongodb"
  }
}
```

Also see [the github readme](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb) as an extra help resource and source code for [AbstractMongoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/AbstractMongoConfiguration.java) if you're interested/curious